# necessary manifest permissions for ad providers?

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

I want to try some different ad providers for my android app. 
Some of them want a lot permissions in the manifest which I don't always find appropriate.

(of course they all need android.permission.INTERNET since they fetch ads from their servers)

For example: Millenial Media wants android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE; a lot of other provider want android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.

If I don't grant these permissions in the manifest does the app work correct anyway or could this cause problems?

And do I get ads from these providers anyway without these manifest-permissions?

**Edit:**
 it's hard to test all SDK's of the ad providers. For MoPub I know it still works if I don't give them android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION - and I get ads from them.

I think I will only get an Error when their SDK-Code is trying to use a Method which needs a permission - but they could catch this. So my question is more:

Do all ad providers handle this correct? And will they then refuse to send ads in general?

**Edit-2:** 
Has anyone had errors/crashes because he didn't grant special permissions requested from the ad-providers SDK?

Answer (score 0):

App will work fine but you will not get the adds.

Answer (score 0):

these are compulsions , you need to add permissions in Android Manifest file .... its compulsion

Answer (score 0):

From the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms)

> If an application needs access to a feature protected by a permission,
>   it must declare that it requires that permission with a
>   `<uses-permission>` element in the manifest. Then, when the application
>   is installed on the device, the installer determines whether or not to
>   grant the requested permission by checking the authorities that signed
>   the application's certificates and, in some cases, asking the user. If
>   the permission is granted, the application is able to use the
>   protected features. If not, its attempts to access those features will
>   simply fail without any notification to the user.

[This is the complete list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) of permissions you have to provide according to your needs

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to handle permissions. My question is: How do the ad providers handle 'missings' permissions? Has anyone experienced errors because of that?

Comment: That depends on the ad provider and their SDK. Generally they will tell in their SDK what all permissions you need to implement to get their ad working in your app.